# Suggestions for vehicle routing problem with priority basis

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization

I have to suggest optimum route for 25 deliveries for single driver and for single depot, but deliveries are labeled as 2,1,0 (High, Medium, Low) based on priority. I studied different optimization tools and also Google OR python library. There is no direct option in Google OR tool to solve my problem. Can anybody suggest or any link which will help to solve my problem.

Comment: Search for TSP (traveling salesman problem) here on Stack Overflow and in Google.

Comment: you can use Google OR tools, you will just have to modify the code to suit your needs, https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing